# How to pass parameter with value in batch?

Tags: batch-file, arguments, default-arguments

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters with value in a batch file?

Here's what the command line should looks like:

```
> example.bat /L:10 /D:30 /R:15
```

And want to be able to pass in the parameters in any order and put their value in specific variables like this:

```
set "loop=10"
set "delay=30"
set "retry=15"
```

I'm using this for now:

```
set "loop=%1"
set "delay=%2"
set "retry=%3"
```

But the problem is if any argument is not passed then it doesnt work and I want to use default value if any argument is not given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see absolutely no need to define variables `loop`, `delay`, and `retry`, when you could so very easily use variable names matching your input, (`L`, `D`, and `R`), or probably better, prefixed; something like `varL`, `varD`, and `varR`.

Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Ensure that there are no existing variables named with var prefixes
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set var) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="

Rem Define your defaults below
Set /A "varD=3,varL=10,varR=5"

Rem Define new variable values from input arguments 
For %%G In ("%*") Do For %%H In (%%~G) Do (Set "_=%%~H"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%I In ("!_:~1,1!=!_:~3!") Do (EndLocal
        Set "var%%I"))

Rem The below lines are included just to show you the defined variables
Set var
Pause
```

Comment: I did that to make less confusion or sound more understandable as it takes variable from a file named `%~n0.ini` (Uses full form in the ini file) if it exists within the same dir. And also my question is how can I pass parameters in random order and still get it working because the original file takes 8 parameters in correct order which I end up messing up sometimes.

Comment: As you can clearly se  @Skyler, my code above, regardless of the fact you did not use a [mcve] for your actual task, takes all three of the input arguments in any order and saves them as variables. It also, as per your supplementary question, substitutes defaults for those which were not passed as arguments. Your issue now seems to be that you have to try to adapt my answer to suit the task, and that is only because you decided not to properly describe that task. Unfortunately, that is on you, and not something I should have to reconsider adapting my answer for.

Comment: Well after trying for a bit, I managed to get it working with my code and also sorry for wasting your time again : (. Thanks @Compo